# Real valued solution

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

I want to obtain the critical points or if you like a real solution for the first derivative of the function set to zero, and the second derivative also vanishes of the function :

```
P[v_] = t/v - (d - 3)/((d - 2) Pi v^2) + 32 t a/((d - 2)^2 v^3) - 
  16 a (d - 5)/((d - 2)^3 Pi v^4) + 256 t a^2/((d - 2)^4 v^5) - 
  256 a^2 (d - 7)/(3 (d - 2)^5 Pi v^6)
```

so I used the code

```
T[rh_] = FullSimplify[D[P[v], v]]
b[rh_] = FullSimplify[D[T[rh_], v]]
Solve[T[rh_] == 0, v, Reals]
Solve[b[rh_] == 0, v, Reals]
```

The true answer is that there are two solutions, which (obviously) I didn't obtain, the two solutions are
[image]

eq 18 is just the first and second derivative of P with respect to v set to zero, these two solutions are real only if 2<d<12.

d and a are constants, t and v are variables, should I consider the first and second derivative with respect to v as a system of 2-equations with two variables t and v to be solved?

Thank you

Comment: What's known about parameters `a,d,t` ?

Comment: d and a are constants, t is also a variable

Comment: That means you try to solve for `t,v`: `Solve[{P'[v] == 0, P''[v] == 0}, {t, v}, Reals]`?

Comment: yes that is true

Comment: You should check, how the solutions are derived in the paper

Comment: Thank you, I slightly edit your code and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
P = Function[{v, t},t/v - (d - 3)/((d - 2) Pi v^2) + 32 t a/((d - 2)^2 v^3) -16 a (d - 5)/((d - 2)^3 Pi v^4) + 256 t a^2/((d - 2)^4 v^5) -256 a^2 (d - 7)/(3 (d - 2)^5 Pi v^6)];

Solve[{Derivative[1, 0][P][v, t] == 0,Derivative[2, 0][P][v, t] == 0}, {t, v}, Reals]
```

Comment: Thank you my man I only needed to edit your anwser so i add `Fullsimplify` and remove reals